# SugarCRM and REST API - Setting Assigned To field and Date fields

Tags: php, api, rest, sugarcrm

I've got a couple fields I'm having a hard time to set with the REST API.

The first is the Assigned To field. I'm trying to set `assigned_user_id` to the `ID` of the user in the `Users` module, but it's not working. What am I missing?

I'm also having trouble setting dates. What format is expected?  I've tried timestamps, but they don't take either.

Here's my array:

```
$args = array(
        array("name" => "installation_or_service_c", "value" => 'Service'),
        array("name" => "dealerconsumer_c", "value" => "Consumer"),
        array("name" => "first_name", "value" => 'Test'),
        array("name" => "last_name", "value" => 'Testerson'),
        array("name" => "phone_home", "value" => '111-111-1111'),
        array("name" => "email1", "value" => 'name@domain.com'),
        array("name" => "status", "value" => "Consumer IN PROCESS"),
        array("name" => "primary_address_street", "value" => '123 Main Street'),
        array("name" => "primary_address_city", "value" => 'Springfield'),
        array("name" => "primary_address_state", "value" => 'MA'),
        array("name" => "primary_address_postalcode", "value" => '11111'),
        array("name" => "primary_address_country", "value" => 'United States'),
        array("name" => "description", "value" => ''),
        array("name" => "send_packet_c", "value" => 'Yes'),
        array("name" => "mailing_list_c", "value" => 'No'),
        array("name" => "consumer_referral_status_c", "value" => 'In Process'),
        array("name" => "assigned_user_id", "value" => '122dc5a7-e2a5-1ad1-ee66-50699ac08d5a'),
        array("name" => "salesman_number_c", "value" => '01'),
        array("name" => "dealer_assigned_date_c", "value" => '06/13/2013')
);
```

The items are the third from the last, and the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it sorted.  The problem with the Assigned To filed was my own fault, using the wrong GUID for the user.  The date is in European format, specifically YYYY-MM-DD